# Min function gives output 6422164 irrespective of the input

Tags: c

I want to implement a function that returns the minimum of four elements. I have written the following code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  int max;

  if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) {
      if (a > d) {
        max = a;
      }
    }
  } else if (b > a) {
    if (b > c) {
      if (b > d) {
        max = b;
      }
    }
  } else if (c > a) {

    if (c > b) {
      if (c > d) {
        max = c;
      }
    }
  } else {
    max = d;
  }
  return max;
}

int main() {
  // initializing int a, b, c, d, max;
  scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
  int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
  printf("%d", ans);

  return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me output `6422164` irrespective of the input. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: always turn on compiler warnings. It'll tell you the issue right away

Comment: It's always a good practice to store those values in an array.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't covered the cases properly, E.g. what if `a=1` and `b=2` and `c=3`. The condition in the second `if` (`b>a`) will be true and the block entered. Then the condition `b>c` will be false and no other block will be entered. Finally the *uninitialised* variable `max` is returned, returning an undefined value which you see as 6422164.

A better way to write it is to initialise `max` to the first value and then compare each value in turn to `max`, updating it if the current number is greater than max.

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d) {
    int max = a;

    if (b > max) max = b;
    if (c > max) max = c;
    if (d > max) max = d;

    return max;
}
```